# Botão submit virar um link normal

Tags: php, html

Necessito que um botão com seus mesmos valores seja "convertido" para um Link normal.

```
<input type="submit" name="idPessoa" id="idPessoa" class="text-success" 
       value="<?php echo $this->idPessoa = $lotacao[$i][3];?>">
```

Existe alguma forma eficaz de fazer isso? Tentei uma ou outra, mas sem sucesso esperado.

Comment: Não pode passar essa informação por um input hidden?

Comment: Tentei algo desse tipo.. coloquei o botão hidden, e criei o link <a href="javascript:document.form.submit();" id="pessoa"> XXXXX </a> mas não foi. Funciona, mas é como se pegasse o mesmo ID então se eu clicar em outro botão de outro ID vai chamar o mesmo anterior.

Comment: Você tem varios forms? E quer que o o input submit vire um <a href="javascript:document.form.submit();" id="pessoa"> XXXXX </a> para submeter esse form em especifico?

Comment: É apenas um form que eu tenho.. e três botões que chamam IDs diferentes. E quero fazer com que virem links, porém eles tem que ter uma ação de botão. (Estranho kkK)

Comment: Porque tem que ser um link? Qual é o problema que tem que resolver? Qual o resultado que espera obter do click no link? Que dados precisa enviar para o servidor? Desculpe todas estas perguntas. Mas sem as resposta eu não consigo entender o que deseja.

Comment: Descobrir que o bootstrap tem algo que já engana legal...

<button type="submit" name="idPessoa" id="idPessoa" class="bt btn-link" style="color: red"                               value="<?php echo $this->idPessoa = $lotacao[$i][3];?>">Reprovado</button>

Comment: @phpricardo atualizei a resposta com uma solução CSS tambem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Se precisa realmente de um link

Basta utilizar este formato:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.nomeDoSeuForm.submit(); return false;">
```

Aplicando ao seu caso:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.nomeDoSeuForm.submit(); return false;"><?php
   echo htmlentities( $this->idPessoa = $lotacao[$i][3] );
?></a>
```

Notar que o `htmlentities()` que eu acrescentei não tem a ver com a pergunta, mas é bom usar para que a acentuação fique OK. Caso suas variáveis já estejam codificadas, pode retirar.

### Se precisa apenas da aparência do link

Basta usar o `input` normal no form, ou mesmo um `button`:

```
<input type="submit" name="idPessoa" id="idPessoa" class="meulink" 
   value="<?php echo $this->idPessoa = $lotacao[$i][3];?>">
```

E estilizar com CSS:

```
.meulink {
   display:inline;
   background:transparent;
   text-decoration: underline;
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #00f;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/yp69ncct)**

Answer (score 2):

Simplesmente construa um link normal, que leve para a página do formulário passando tudo o que você quer por GETs, diretamente na URL.

Construa o link, pegando o valor do action do formulário e adicione a informação do input submit, passando esse valor por um GET.

No seu caso, algo assim:

```
<a href="http://linkdoform.com.br/pagina.php?idPessoa=<?php echo $this->idPessoa = $lotacao[$i][3];?>"> Nome da ação</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso te aconselho usar jQuery, segue um pequeno exemplo de como eu faria isso, lembrando que você vai precisar importar a biblioteca jQuery.
Eu utilizei um `input hidden`, passando o valor dela no submit com atributo [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Formulário em HTML com o jQuery que pode ser o min ou uncrompressed.

```
<script src="js/uncrompressed/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<form method="post">

    <input type="text" name="txtNome" />
    <input type="hidden" id="valor" name="valor" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="$('#valor').val('opcao1')" value="Opção1" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="$('#valor').val('opcao2')" value="Opção2" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="$('#valor').val('opcao3')" value="Opção3" />

</form>
```

E o código em PHP que eu utilizei:

```
<?php

    if($_POST){

        $getNome = $_POST["txtNome"];

        $valorDoBotao = $_POST["valor"];

        if($valorDoBotao == "opcao1"){
            header('Location: seulink?nome='.$getNome);
            // faca isso
        }

        if($valorDoBotao == "opcao2"){
            header('Location: seulink?nome='.$getNome);
            // faca isso
        }

        if($valorDoBotao == "opcao3"){
            header('Location: seulink?nome='.$getNome);
            // faca isso
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Agradeço pela intenção mano, mas ai você ainda está usando BUTTON o que eu quero é usar LINK

Comment: Você quer usar um link que de um submit no formulário enviando os parâmetros para este link?

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo. :]

Comment: Mas do jeito que eu mostrei ele encaminha para um link utilizando o header('Location : seulink'.$parametro.), que creio que você queria.

Comment: Pesquisei a respeito e possui uma dúvida parecida com a sua neste link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022167/jquery-add-post-variables-to-a-href-link